# python : why is my is this IF AND failing so badly...

Tags: python

Below are four functions:

A(), B(), and A_B() All return the expected results. A_B_2() on the other hand fails, despite being essentially identical.

What I can't seem to figure out why the IF AND statements in A_B_2 are being treated differently despite being identical to A_B.

```
def A(the_filter):
    print "start A()"
    for o in range(length):
        for x in range(length):
            if the_filter == "A" and x < 3 :
                print the_filter, o, x+1
            else:
                print the_filter, o, x-x
    return "end A()"

def B(the_filter):
    print "start B()"
    for o in range(length):
        for x in range(length):
            if the_filter == "B" and o != x :
                print the_filter, o, x
            else:
                print the_filter, "fail"
    return "end B()"

def A_B(the_filter):
    print "start A_B()"
    for o in range(length):
        for x in range(length):
            if the_filter == "A" :
                if x < 3 :
                    print the_filter, o, x+1
                else:
                    print the_filter, o, x-x
            if the_filter == "B" :
                if o != x :
                    print the_filter, o, x
                else:
                    print the_filter, "fail"
    return "end A_B()"

def A_B_2(the_filter):
    print "start A_B_2()"
    for o in range(length):
        for x in range(length):
            if the_filter == "A" and x < 3 :
                print the_filter, o, x+1
            else:
                print the_filter, o, x-x
            if the_filter == "B" and o != x :
                print the_filter, o, x
            else:
                print the_filter, "fail"
    return "A_B_2()"

length = 3
print A("A"), "\n"
print B("B"), "\n"
print A_B("A"), "\n"
print A_B("B"), "\n"
print A_B_2("A"), "\n"
print A_B_2("B"), "\n"
```

The output I'm getting for these for is:

```
start A()
A 0 1
A 0 2
A 0 3
A 1 1
A 1 2
A 1 3
A 2 1
A 2 2
A 2 3
end A() 

start B()
B fail
B 0 1
B 0 2
B 1 0
B fail
B 1 2
B 2 0
B 2 1
B fail
end B() 

start A_B()
A 0 1
A 0 2
A 0 3
A 1 1
A 1 2
A 1 3
A 2 1
A 2 2
A 2 3
end A_B() 

start A_B()
B fail
B 0 1
B 0 2
B 1 0
B fail
B 1 2
B 2 0
B 2 1
B fail
end A_B() 

start A_B_2()
A 0 1
A fail
A 0 2
A fail
A 0 3
A fail
A 1 1
A fail
A 1 2
A fail
A 1 3
A fail
A 2 1
A fail
A 2 2
A fail
A 2 3
A fail
A_B_2() 

start A_B_2()
B 0 0
B fail
B 0 0
B 0 1
B 0 0
B 0 2
B 1 0
B 1 0
B 1 0
B fail
B 1 0
B 1 2
B 2 0
B 2 0
B 2 0
B 2 1
B 2 0
B fail
A_B_2()
```

Comment: They are not identical. `A_B_2` has extra conditions on the `if the_filter ==` lines. What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: Yeah what's the expected output.Also, please indent your code properly and paste it so we can run it on our systems

Comment: I'm expecting `A_B` and `A_B_2()` to produce the exact same output because when you look at the output you'll see "A fail" which is technically impossible because the criteria required to the `print "fail" ` line are not satisfied by "A".

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the following part of `A_B`:

```
if the_filter == "A" :
    if x < 3 :
        print the_filter, o, x+1
    else:
        print the_filter, o, x-x
```

is not equivalent to the following fragment of `A_B_2`:

```
if the_filter == "A" and x < 3 :
    print the_filter, o, x+1
else:
    print the_filter, o, x-x
```

Namely, if `the_filter` equals `"B"`, the first version will do nothing (because `the_filter == "A"` evaluates to `False`), while the second version will execute the `else` branch (because `the_filter == "A" and x < 3` evaluates to `False`).

This results e.g. in the appearing of the first line (`B 0 0`) printed by `A_B_2("B")`, comparing to what is output by `A_B("B")`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.\n

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback Alex. (above)  After a little sleep I think I've wrapped my head around this and your response makes sense.

In order for  A_B_2()  to return the same output  A_B() i needed to replace the `else` with an `elif` to ensure `the_filter` was still consider in second portion of the statement. Thus:

`def A_B_2(the_filter):
    print "start A_B_2()"
    for o in range(length):
        for x in range(length):
            if the_filter == "A" and x < 3 :
                print the_filter, o, x+1
            elif the_filter == "A" :
                print the_filter, o, x-x
            if the_filter == "B" and o != x :
                print the_filter, o, x
            elif the_filter == "B":
                print the_filter, "fail"
    return "A_B_2()"`